# How to create a POST End point for a GET End point?

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, endpoint

I am attempting to create a Node.JS website, but I need to create two end points in order for my IOT to work properly. The objective is to create two end points, a POST end point in which it retrieves JSON data for the GET end point, in order to load the First and Last name of the reservation on the welcome page. How can I accomplish that?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

// Moment.js
var moment = require('moment');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Json File
const json = require("./data.json");

// Javascript Files
const welcomeTime = require('./public/javascript/welcomeTime');

// Load View Engine
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', 
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

// GET Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.render('index', {
        title: 'NodePark',
        hotel: 'NodePark',

        // This woould be the json data I need from the payload
        firstName: json.payload.data.Source_FirstName,
        lastname: json.payload.data.Source_LastName,
        // end of data needed

        date: moment().format('ll'),
        time: moment().format('LT'),
        currentHour: welcomeTime.dayTime()
    });
 });

// POST Route
app.post('/hotel', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/', {
    });
});

// Start Server
app.listen(5000, function(){
    console.log('Port 5000 LIVE.');
});
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. Your page is initially rendered via the `.get('/')` route. After that page has loaded, at some time in the future, you want to post reservation data to the page?

OR

You are just trying to initially render the data from `./data.json` ??

Comment: Initially it rendered the .get('/') route but I Need it first to make a POST end point in which it retrieves the json data for the GET route to have the info to refresh or load the page with the info. I have never done this, I am not sure how to tackle this. Is that more clear?

Comment: Where are you getting the data, from the user, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here.  But I'll take a stab.

Sounds like you have data you want to retrieve from both your get and your post routes.  Just put that data in a function, and call that function from both your routes.  But I will say, if you have a "POST" endpoint which is merely just retrieving data from your "GET" endpoint, I would severely question why you are "POSTING" to begin with.  You're not creating any new resource or anything.

Anyhow, here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

// Moment.js
const moment = require('moment');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Json File
const json = require('./data.json');

// Javascript Files
const welcomeTime = require('./public/javascript/welcomeTime');

// Load View Engine
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  extname:       'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  layoutsDir:    `${__dirname}/views/layouts/`
}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

const getMyData = () => ({
  title: 'NodePark',
  hotel: 'NodePark',

  // This woould be the json data I need from the payload
  firstName: json.payload.data.Source_FirstName,
  lastname:  json.payload.data.Source_LastName,
  // end of data needed

  date:        moment().format('ll'),
  time:        moment().format('LT'),
  currentHour: welcomeTime.dayTime()
});

// GET Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', getMyData());
});

// POST Route
app.post('/hotel', (req, res) => {
  const theData = getMyData(); // use it here???  I have no idea....
  res.redirect('/', {
  });
});

// Start Server
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Port 5000 LIVE.');
});
```

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for your help, I appreciate it. But I think my wording is unclear as I am also a little confused. I need to create a POST end point in which I retrieve data (this case json first & last name). Then I pass that data to my GET Route so that it can display the first & last name to the display. Are you saying why do I need a GET route in the first place? My partner says he needs a POST endpoint for the IOT service to work.

Comment: A `POST` request to retrieve (`GET`) data does not make sense. @FreshOceans